# Non-friend, non-member function accessing private data member

Tags: overloading, operator-keyword, non-member-functions

I am trying to use the `istream` function below to access the private data members numerator and denominator, however, I am getting errors about it being private. `istream` is a non-friend, non-member function (I cannot make it a friend). I understand that I cannot directly access the private members, but shouldn't my reference to `MyFraction` allow me to?

```
std::istream & operator>>(std::istream & sin, MyFraction & frac)

    {
        return sin >> frac.numerator >> frac.denominator;
    }
```

I have getters (`getNumerator()` and `getDenominator()`), however, I cannot access the members that way either. I also get an error:

> ambiguous overload for operator>>.

My getters do return by value:

```
inline int MyFraction::getNumerator() const
{
    return numerator;
}

inline unsigned int MyFraction::getDenominator() const
{
    return denominator;
}
```

What am I overlooking in this function?

Comment: What does `MyFraction` look like? I suspect your getters return by value rather than by reference. If they returned by reference, then `sin >> frac.getNumerator() >> frac.getDenominator()` should work. Otherwise, you have to declare this function as a friend inside your `MyFraction`.

Comment: The "ambiguous overload" error makes me think you are trying to (re-)define a function that already exists...